"qt.bluetooth.darwin: Manually interrupting IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry"
Пишу приложение для работы с Bluetooth с использованием Qt и С++. Приложение собирается и запускается, но постоянно выдаёт сообщение:

"qt.bluetooth.darwin: Manually interrupting IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry"

Устройства тоже находит, но по какой-то причине не видит их адреса.
Код:
#include <QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QBluetoothLocalDevice>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceInfo>
#include <QBluetoothUuid>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class BluetoothScanner : public QObject
{

public:
    BluetoothScanner()
    {
        _discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this);
        connect(_discoveryAgent, &QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::deviceDiscovered,
                this, &BluetoothScanner::deviceDiscovered);
        connect(_discoveryAgent, &QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::finished,
                this, &BluetoothScanner::deviceScanFinished);
    }
    void StartScan()
    {
        _discoveryAgent->start();
    }

private slots:
    void deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo& device)
    {
        qDebug() << "New device:" << device.name()
                 << "Device address: " << device.address();
    }

    void deviceScanFinished()
    {
        qDebug() << "Scan finished";
    }

private:
    QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent *_discoveryAgent;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QBluetoothLocalDevice device;

    if (!device.isValid())
    {
        qWarning() << "Whoops";
        return -1;
    }
    device.powerOn();
    BluetoothScanner scanner;
    scanner.StartScan();

    return a.exec();
}

Файл pro:
QT += core bluetooth

CONFIG += c++17 cmdline

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
macos: QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = ../Info.qmake.macos.plist
# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

Вывод приложения:
2024-10-21 10:48:50.587 Tbl4[1508:20200] -[IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry initWithDelegate:] -  0x600001ba4c30
qt.bluetooth.darwin: Manually interrupting IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry
New device: "" Device address:  "00:00:00:00:00:00"
New device: "Apple watch" Device address:  "00:00:00:00:00:00"
New device: "RK-G210S" Device address:  "00:00:00:00:00:00"
New device: "RK-G210S" Device address:  "00:00:00:00:00:00"
New device: "[TV] Samsung 7 Series (40)" Device address:  "00:00:00:00:00:00"

Версия Qt: 6.8.0
Версия MacOs: 15.0.1

Если судить по исходнику, то, по всей видимости, процесс обнаружения на маках bluetooth-устройств, по каким-то причинам не прерывается (понятия не имею, как это должно работать на уровне ядра на маках. Может быть как работает, так и правильно), поэтому его (процесс) останавливают (зачем? Почему? не знаю) по таймеру ("вручную"), выдавая соответствующее сообщение. То есть никаких проблем, просто особенность реализации работы с зубом на Qt, на макаха https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtconnectivity/+/367668/6/src/bluetooth/darwin/btdeviceinquiry.mm#51
